# Is there a way to insert elements only to specified parts of XML using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, xml.etree

I have an XML in the following form

```
<PROJECT>
    <SUBJECT>GEOGRAPHY</SUBJECT>
    <PROJECT_NAME>THE-WORLD</PROJECT_NAME>
    <NAME>COUNTRIES</NAME>
    <AGE>100</AGE>
    <DOMAIN>MAPS</DOMAIN>
    <EUROPE>
        <WESTERN>
            <TYPE>ABC</TYPE>
            <TYPE>MNO</TYPE>
            <COUNTRY>
                <NAME>MONACO</NAME>
                <DETAILS>           
                     <EUROPE CAPITAL="Monaco" />
                     <EUROPE population= 123456 />
                     <EUROPE currency="euro" />
               <DETAILS> 
            </COUNTRY>
            <COUNTRY>
                <NAME>MALTA</NAME>
                <DETAILS>
                    <EUROPE CAPITAL="Valletta" />
                    <EUROPE population=123456 />
                    <EUROPE currency="euro" />
                </DETAILS>
                <DETAILS>
                   <EUROPE FOOD="Pizza" />
                   <EUROPE LANGUAGE="Spanish" />
                 </DETAILS>
            </COUNTRY>
            <COUNTRY>
                 <NAME>ANDORRA</NAME>
                 <DETAILS>
                   <EUROPE CAPITAL="Andorra la Vella" />
                   <EUROPE population=123456 />
                   <EUROPE currency="euro" />
                 </DETAILS>
                 <DETAILS>
                   <EUROPE FOOD="PIZZA" />
                   <EUROPE LANGUAGE="Spanish" />
                 </DETAILS>
           </ANDORRA>
        </WESTERN>
    </EUROPE>
</PROJECT>
```

Now, I need to add a new tag  to all the country tags(**COUNTRY/DETAILS and COUNTRY/DETAILS**) apart from the first one **COUNTRY/DETAILS** like this

```
            <COUNTRY>
                <NAME>MONACO</NAME>
                <DETAILS>           
                     <EUROPE CAPITAL="Monaco" />
                     <EUROPE population= 123456 />
                     <EUROPE currency="euro" />
               <DETAILS> 
            </COUNTRY>
            <COUNTRY>
                <NAME>MALTA</NAME>
                <DETAILS>
                    <EUROPE CAPITAL="Valletta" />
                    <EUROPE population=123456 />
                    <EUROPE currency="euro" />
                    
                    <EUROPE driving_side = "right" />
                </DETAILS>
                <DETAILS>
                   <EUROPE FOOD="Pizza" />
                   <EUROPE LANGUAGE="Spanish" />
                   
                   <EUROPE driving_side = "right" />
                 </DETAILS>
            </COUNTRY>
            <COUNTRY>
                 <NAME>ANDORRA</NAME>
                 <DETAILS>
                   <EUROPE CAPITAL="Andorra la Vella" />
                   <EUROPE population=123456 />
                   <EUROPE currency="euro" />
                   
                   <EUROPE driving_side = "right" />
                 </DETAILS>
                 <DETAILS>
                   <EUROPE FOOD="PIZZA" />
                   <EUROPE LANGUAGE="Spanish" />
                   
                   <EUROPE driving_side = "right" />
                 </DETAILS>
           </COUNTRY>
```

I tried the following approach but was able to insert only to the first occurrence of the tag. Could someone please help me with this?

```
tasks = root.findall('.//EUROPE/WESTERN/COUNTRY')
new = ET.fromstring('<EUROPE driving_side = "right" /')
for index, task in enumerate(tasks):
    task.find('.//DETAILS').insert(3, new)
```

Comment: It is task for XSLT

Comment: No the normal XML itself @Yitzhak Khabinsky

Comment: I don't understand your comment

Comment: I told that it's not a task for XSLT, I have a normal XML file that I need to modify using a python file. Hence I'm trying to manipulate this xml file using the above python code